# Renombrando archivos con python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando cambiar el nombre de unas bases de datos que inician con un código del día de descarga

```
17012020_OBJ_ARCHIVO_A
17012020_ARCHIVO_A
```

a

```
OBJ_ARCHIVO_A
ARCHIVO_A
```

El codigo que estoy ocupando es el siguiente, pero al ejecutarlo no aparece nada y tampoco me aparece algún codigo de error

```
import os

carpeta = 'C:\\ev\\'

def codigo_gc(gc):
    cod_gc= "{}".format(gc)  #Este es el nombre del archivo que buscará el código (Reflexion)
    nombre_final = "{}.csv".format(gc)

    for filename in os.listdir(carpeta):
        if cod_gc in filename.lower():
            print("Renombrando {} como {}".format(filename, nombre_final))
            os.rename(carpeta + filename, carpeta + nombre_final)
            break

codigo_gc("OBJ_ARCHIVO_A")
codigo_gc("ARCHIVO_A")
```

Comment: ¿Qué base de datos estás utilizando o esto es irrelevante? ¿Son archivos o carpetas?

Comment: Estoy utilizando archivos .csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que te falta pasar el `cod_gc` a minúsculas, prueba a cambiar la línea:

```
cod_gc= "{}".format(gc)
```

Por:

```
cod_gc= "{}".format(gc).lower()
```

Comment: Hola Roberto! He realizado nuevamente lo que comentas y me ha funcionado, ya que al parecer el código es sensible a mayúsculas. Muchas gracias!